# How to resolve error in Array Pair in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-transitions

```
fun sharedElementTransition(view: View) {
     val pair: Array<Pair<View, String>> = Array<Pair<View,String>>(size = 3) /ht/getting issue 
     pair[0] = Pair<View,String>(imglogo, "logo_shared")
     pair[1] = Pair<View,String>(txvshared, "smartherd_shared")
     pair[2] = Pair<View,String>(imgProfilepic, "pic_shared")
     var options : ActivityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, *pair)
```

No value passed in Parameter Init. Also, is there any other pass value in Pair? There are multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it how to initialize each element in the list like this:

`val list = Array<Pair<Int,Int>>(size = 3) { Pair(0,0) }`

which will make a list of 3 items which are all `Pair(0,0)`

---

You can also base the initialize the elements based off of the index like this:

```
val list = Array<Pair<Int,Int>>(size = 3) { index ->
   Pair(index, index) 
}
```

which will make a list that looks like:

`[Pair(0,0), Pair(1,1), Pair(2,2)]`

---

For your case try this:

```
val pair = Array<Pair<View,String>>(size = 3) { index ->
    when(index) {
        0 -> Pair(imglogo, "logo_shared")
        1 -> Pair(txvshared, "smartherd_shared")
        2 -> Pair(imgProfilepic, "pic_shared")
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rahul if you need to initialize a list with the elements being null you can make it like this: `var list = Array<Pair<Int,Int>?>(size = 3) { null }` and then update the elements later. But you can not initialize a list of size 3 with non-null elements, and not provide an initializer for them.

Comment: val pair = Array<Pair<View,String>?>(size = 3) { (null)}


        pair[0] = Pair<View,String>(imglogo, "logo_shared")
        pair[1] = Pair<View,String>(txvshared, "smartherd_shared")
        pair[2] = Pair<View,String>(imgProfilepic, "pic_shared")


        var options : ActivityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, pair)
        var intent : Intent = Intent(this,SharedActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent,options.toBundle())
     Type mismatch: inferred type is Array<Pair<View, String>?> but Pair<View!, String!>! was expected

Comment: @Rahul Try the code snippet i just added to my answer to initialize your list, tenfours answer will also solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

The Array constructor expects a lambda argument to define the initial value for each index of the array. Since you already know what you're going to put on it, and the values are not based on what their array index is, it makes more sense to use the `arrayOf` function to create your array. You don't need to keep repeating the generic types, because they can be inferred.

```
fun sharedElementTransition(view: View) {
    val pair: Array<Pair<View, String>> = arrayOf(
        Pair(imglogo, "logo_shared"),
        Pair(txvshared, "smartherd_shared"),
        Pair(imgProfilepic, "pic_shared")
    )
    var options : ActivityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, *pair)
    //...
}
```